# An Involution on Integer Sequences

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, involutions, integer-sequences

My question is the following: Let $C:= \{(f_1,f_2,f_3,..): \text{each } f_i \text{ is a non-negative integer and only finitely many nonzero}\}$. I am looking for an involution $\phi: C \xrightarrow{} C$ such that

- $\phi \circ \phi = \text{identity on C}$
- Moreover, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i \cdot i$ is invariant under $\phi$. In other words, let $f = (f_1,f_2,f_3,\cdots) \in C$ and $\phi(f) = (g_1,g_2,g_3,\cdots) \in C$. Then, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i \cdot i = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g_i \cdot i$.
- We want the set of fixed points to be as small as possible, i.e we want the set $\{f \in C: \phi(f)=f\}$ to be small.

Obviously, I am looking for something which is not the identity function:)

**Motivation:** I am not sure whether the motivation is related to the answer of the question or not, let me give it anyway. There is a well-known involution in integer partitions, namely the conjugation. It interchanges rows and columns of the Ferrer diagram of a partition. An integer partition $\lambda$ can be represented as a sequence $(f_1,f_2,f_3, \cdots)$ in $C$, where $C$ is defined as above. Intuitively, $f_i$ is the number of times, the part $i$ appears in $\lambda$.

For example, $5 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1$ can be represented as $(1 , 3 , 1 , 0 , 2, 0 , 0 , \cdots)$.

It seems to me, the conjugation operation is not easily representable using the sequence representation of the partition. Therefore, I am looking for an involution which is easily representable("more natural") using sequence representation. The requirement for the invariance of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i \cdot i$ comes from integer partition motivation.

**PS:** If you have other ideas, which does not satisfy the requirements but the function $\phi$ is natural to consider in some other areas of mathematics, I want to learn them as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the slightly trivial $ \phi(1, 1) = (0, 2)$ and vice versa, and otherwise $ \phi(f) = f$?

Comment: This does not work actually, because $(1,1)$ is the partition $2+1$ and $(0,2)$ is the partition $2+2$ so their weight is not the same. I guess, you mean $\phi(1,0,1) =(0,2)$. This works, but rather artifically defined. I am looking for something which more "natural". Thanks for the answer anyway:)

Comment: @ALNS Re: you last comment, define “natural”. This question seems to vague; you are asking us to design an involution, without telling us what properties this involution should have.

Comment: Ah, I meant $ \phi (2, 0) = (0, 1)$ with natural numbers starting from 1, where $ 2 \times 1  + 0 \times 2 = 0 \times 1 + 1 \times 2$. My point is that you'd have to be much more specific about what kind of (non-identity) involution you're looking for. Namely, any involution is made up up distinct pairs with $ \phi (x) = y$, and otherwise $ \phi (z) = z$. EG Are you interested in making the $(x, y)$ sets as large as possible?

Comment: @MikeEarnest, I am not sure. However, a good rule of thumb is that we want the set of fixed points as small as possible. Let me edit the question and add this as well.